# How to remove weird viewport mask

Tags: 3d-view

I was messing about with keyboard combos in 2.80 alpha trying to remember how to add a render preview rectangle, however I seem to have done something that has masked my model in 3D space, which I can rotate around. It's on a global level as multiple objects are being masked the same way.

I am lost as to what I've done and how to clear it. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> doesn't seem to work.

Hopefully this is something easy and I'm having a brain fart, otherwise it's an embarrassment to say I've been using Blender for 15 years...

[image: Mask]

Comment: It seems to be per-viewport, as I just created a new one and it didn't travel across. Really curious as to what this feature is though, as nothing comes up under "clear" in the menu...

Comment: just curious, why aren't you using blender 2.80 stable?  (also, a preview rectangle uses the shortcut, **ctrl b**

Comment: Just haven't got around to downloading the stable release yet. I use blender about once a year ha. And cheers, yeah it had escaped my muscle memory, too used to Adobe's M for marquee

Comment: I had the same problems a few days ago. The solution I found was restarting Blender.

Comment: Maybe it´s your viewport clipping? IN the "N" toolbar on the right side of your viewport, there is a tab called view. At the top you can change the clip start and end. Hope htat helps! :)

Comment: @morph3us Perhaps, but it definitely happened after I drew some form of rectangle. Not sure if it's a bug or just some undocumented feature!

Answer (score 1):

I had used this masking method before on an older file, but then forgot what it is and how to use it. Wanting to remove it so I can see the full model, I looked it up online & found this post.

The answer with <kbd>B</kbd> helped, as I tried different combinations. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>(on Windows) to remove it and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> again to draw a new one.

From this shortcut I managed to search & apparently it's called a "Clipping Border" or **"Clipping Region"**.